# Docker Nodejs Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I want to use Redis with my express server in docker. I am using docker-compose to build my app with Redis. Here is my code for **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR '/var/www/app'
```

Here is the code for the **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: cache
  expose:
    - 6379
app:
  build: ./
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/app
  links:
    - redis
  ports:
    - 7000:7000
  environment:
    - REDIS_URL = redis
    - NODE_ENV=development
    - PORT=7000
  command:
    sh -c 'npm i && node server.js'
```

I am not able to debug why it is refusing to connect even if I expose port 6379 in the docker-compose.yml file.
Here is my code for the server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const redis =require("redis")

let client=redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL)

client.on('connect',()=>{
  console.log("redis connected")
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Error " + err);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening in port: ${port}`);
});
```

I have used the below commands to build the app.

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Try remove spaces in `REDIS_URL = redis`

Comment: Looks like redis connection is ignoring your env variable and trying to connect to localhost. Can you debug the value of the env var from your node script? (Also, please add the output in your question, not only in the title)

Comment: try a valid redis URL, like `redis://redis:6379`

Comment: @zigarn After removing the extra spaces, I have logged env variable REDIS_URL and it showing me the output as "redis" as per the code given above.

Comment: @ozlevka Thanks for the suggestion, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by just removing the spaces in-between and changed the first line after the environment to REDIS_URL=redis://cache
Thanks to @ozlevka

Answer (score -2):

```
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: cache
  ports:
    - 6379:6379
app:
  build: ./
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/app
  ports:
    - 7000:7000
  environment:
    - REDIS_URL=localhost
    - NODE_ENV=development
    - PORT=7000
  command:
    sh -c 'npm i && node server.js'
```

I have added `ports` to redis and removed `links`. Please try this and update.

Comment: The below error is showing after I replaced your code in the docker-compose.yml file.

RangeError: The redis url must begin with slashes "//" or contain slashes after the redis protocol

Comment: @ANKUSHKUMAR try now, with localhost

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked finally. The problem was the spaces as @ozlevka suggested.

Comment: `network_mode: "host"` generally disables Docker's networking setup.  That's not necessary just to connect between containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, its true.. I suggested it as he couldnt run it. I will remove host part from the answer.. Thanks for pointing that